# Named Parameters in Snowflake Stored Procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Are you able to call Snowflake stored procedures with named parameters or does it rely on positional arguments?
For example, I would like to execute:

```
CALL usp_my_proc(number1=2,number2=3)
```

instead of:

```
CALL usp_my_proc(2,3)
```

Answer (score 3):

`CALL` can only be called by positional arguments:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/call.html

(and the type matters, you can have multiple procedures with the same name, but for different types)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use both positional and named parameters when calling a stored procedure:

> [CALL](https://docs.snowflake.com/sql-reference/sql/call)
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
>  CALL <procedure_name> ( [ [ <arg_name> => ] <arg> , ... ] )
>  [ INTO :<snowflake_scripting_variable> ]
> ```
>
> Required Parameters:
>
> ```
> procedure_name ( [ [ arg_name => ] arg , ... ] )
> ```
>
> Specifies the identifier (procedure_name) for the procedure to call and any input arguments.
>
> You can either specify the input arguments **by name (arg_name => arg)** or **by position (arg)**.

Related: [UDFs, UDTFs, and Stored Procedures Support Passing Arguments by Name](https://docs.snowflake.com/release-notes/2023-06#udfs-udtfs-and-stored-procedures-support-passing-arguments-by-name)

---

Provided code works "as-is":

```
CALL usp_my_proc(number1 => 2, number2 => 3);
```

---

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_power(a INT, b INT)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN POWER(a, b);
END;
```

a) positional arguments

```
CALL sp_power(2, 3);
-- 8

CALL sp_power(3, 2);
-- 9
```

b) named arguments

```
CALL sp_power(a => 2, b => 3);
-- 8

CALL sp_power(a => 3, b => 2);
-- 9

CALL sp_power(b => 2, a => 3);
-- 9

CALL sp_power(b => 3, a => 2);
-- 8
```

c) mixed arguments

```
CALL sp_power(b => 2, 3);
-- Error: illegal mixing of named and positional arguments for function SP_POWER
```